# Clone form design and code with button

Tags: c#, button, clone, counter

i have a really simple counter application, I made in C#.
Now what i want to know is it possible to clone the form design and code, so there are 2 counter's instead of one. with a button.

they both have to be working.

i'm an beginner.. so that's why i ask if this is possible.

So from this (this is what i currently have, without clone button):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASMY4.jpg

to this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/acluZ.jpg

this is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void counteradd()
    {
        int current1 = Convert.ToInt32(totaltb.Text);
        current1++;
        totaltb.Text = Convert.ToString(current1);
    }

    public void counterreduce()
    {
        int current2 = Convert.ToInt32(totaltb.Text);
        current2--;
        totaltb.Text = Convert.ToString(current2);
    }

    public void counterreset()
    {
        totaltb.Text = ("0");
    }

    private void reducebttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counterreduce();
    }

    private void resetbttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counterreset();
    }

    private void addbttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counteradd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply duplicating the controls and laying them out on the form will result in messy code. The "clone' that you are referring to would be to build the functional piece as a user-control, and then add that as a control to your form.